# Change given HTTP referer url

Tags: php, redirect

does someone know how to change the HTTP referer URL your website gives when redirecting.

I have the following problem:
I own four websites. Most traffic comes in on website A. Because my guest want to download stuff i redirect them to my other website B, C and D. This to keep the server running website A clean and fast.

Now i have come to the point that there are a lot of posts redirecting to a third party. This third party can see that these people are redirected from website B, C or D.

The point is that i want the third party to know that these people originally came from website A. Therefor i want to give the URL from website A as HTTP referer URL when people actually come from B, C, or D.

Is this possible? In my eyes the solution should look something like extra code on the page people are redirected from.

Comment: @Rooster — There is no way to tell a client what HTTP headers to send to a third party site (other than when using XMLHttpRequest, but there are limits to that, and it isn't being used here).

Comment: That sounds valid but is it not possible for site B to say that his name is A so that A is given as referer URL to the third party?

Comment: @Quentin ohhhhh yeah.  I've been scraping a lot lately and am stuck thinking in cUrl mode.  Nice catch.

Comment: @Embed — No, tt is not possible for a website to tell a browser to lie to another website about where it has been.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need change the HTTP_REFERER, and to tell the truth, I believe it is not possible.

So, you have a lot solutions, but you need sent a parameter for everything works:

For example:

- The user is on the site A.
- The user click in any link for go to site B.
- This link have a parameter, with url or some code to identify site A (parent/referer), for example: http://www.siteB.com?paremeter=siteA.com
- Now you can you the solutions below

### Session

Put in session the referer url, when user visit the website A

```
$_SESSION['referer'] = YOUR_URL_HERE
```

### Cookies

```
setcookie("referer", YOUR_URL_HERE, time()+86400); // expire in 24 hours
...
$referer = $_COOKIE["referer"];
```

### Login/User informations

When the user login, put this information in his session, for example (in $_SESSION var)

```
$_SESSION['User']['id'] = 1;
$_SESSION['User']['name'] = 'Patrick';
$_SESSION['User']['referer'] = YOUR_URL_HERE;
```

Comment: This is nice but if a visitor goes from website B to the website of the third party the sessions, cookies or user-info is left unused and the third party still sees website B as referer right?

Comment: In this case you can sent a parameter (GET) when user goes to other website from the primary (http://www.website2.com?referer=website1.com). And then, set this information in your session (just one time)

Comment: But that does not cover websites he does not have control of.

Comment: Yes I know that, but, apparently is the only solution. Or you need create a `Single Sign On` system. But just to be clear: this solution works very well, if siteA is always the primary site, so any link to the secondary site from it will send the referer parameter.